# How to convert an int to string

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ function and I would like to know how to convert an `int` to a `string` for the `else` clause of the `if` statement.

```
string afficherValeurNominal(int val)
{
    string valAffiche = "";
    if (val == 11) // carte j
    {
        valAffiche = "V";
    }
    else if (val == 12) // carte Q
    {
        valAffiche = "D";
    }
    else if (val == 13) // carte k
    {
        valAffiche = "R";
    }
    else
    {
        valAffiche = val;
    }
    return valAffiche;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `switch (val)` instead of repeated `else if`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

```
valAffiche = std::to_string(val);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int a = 22;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string str = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boost library.

```
int i = 42;
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.